# How to drop all the data in xtdb during local development

Tags: database, clojure, xtdb

During development I find that there's a lot of resources that get "left behind" on my local xtdb server.

What's the best way to clear this data locally without restarting my repl?

Answer (score 1):

While posing the question I thought of the answer:

```clj
;; Given some `xtdb-node`
(let [res (xt/q (xt/db xtdb-node)
                '{:find [id]
                  :where [[id :xt/id _]]})
      ids (map first res)]
  (->> ids
       (mapv (fn [id] [::xt/delete id]))
       (xt/submit-tx xtdb-node)))
```

Just search for all documents with the `:xt/id` key as that is a [requirement](https://docs.xtdb.com/language-reference/datalog-transactions/#document) of xtdb.